# Error When imported Firebase packages in flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:1208:6: Error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
}());
^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart:1859:6: Error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.

```
}());
 ^
```

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: ????
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value ?

when i delete the imported package of firebase the project running but if it's imported the project can't be running

Comment: this error happens after i updated the flutter SDK to the latest version, and it only happens when i load the firebase core package

Comment: you can add some style to your errors to make them beautiful.

Comment: try upgrading/downgrading the core package and if required the others(firebase dependencies)